# Como consultar 2 colunas em um único input text

Tags: php, html, pdo, input

Olá,
Como faço pra usar um unico input text para consultar 2 colunas?
Atualmente meu código tem um input=select e um input=text mas no text que quero que consulte 2 colunas.. como faço isso na consulta sql?
Repare que no meu input=text no placeholder eu quero buscar pelo número do "BEM" ou a "Descrição" do item.. Alguém me da uma luz?

```
$query = ("SELECT bem, des_bem, revenda FROM AFX_BEM WHERE revenda LIKE :rev AND des_bem LIKE :bd  "); 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':rev', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':bd', '%' . $var2 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

> html

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="lista.php" method="get">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="revenda">Pesquisar</label>      

             <select class="form-control" name="revenda" style="width: 140px" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
                       <option value="<?php echo $_GET["revenda"] 

                       ?>" selected><?php if(isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) { 
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 1 ) { echo "Piracicaba"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 2 ) { echo "Botucatu"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 3 ) { echo "São Manuel"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 4 ) { echo "Lençóis Paulista"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 5 ) { echo "Jaú"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 6 ) { echo "Ibitinga"; }

                       } else {  ?>Revenda <?php } ?></option>
                        <?php
                            $linha2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            foreach($linha2 as $listar2){

                        ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $listar2["REVENDA"]; ?>">
    <?php echo utf8_encode($listar2["RAZAO_SOCIAL"]);    ?>
 </option>
                        <?php
                            }       
                        ?>   

                        </select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="bemdesc" id="bemdesc" placeholder="BEM ou Descrição" <?php if(!isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) { ?> hidden  <?php } ?> >
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" <?php if(!isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) { ?> hidden  <?php } ?>><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça da seguinte maneira, inserindo mais uma cláusula na condição de sua consulta:

```
$query = ("SELECT bem, des_bem, revenda FROM AFX_BEM WHERE revenda LIKE :rev AND ( des_bem LIKE :dbd OR bem LIKE :bd ) "); 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':rev', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':dbd', '%' . $var2 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':bd', '%' . $var2 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: eu tinha tentado fazer isso.. mas dai minha consulta não retorna nada

Comment: Entendi sua questão, ajustei a consulta, tenta novamente agora.

Comment: ainda nem retorno.. mas fiz a mesma consulta no banco colocando os parâmetros manualmente e retornou valores normal.. acredito que o problema agora esteja no tratamento dos parâmetros no PDO.. eu posso estar usando o mesmo bindvalue 2 vezes?

Comment: Eu consegui da seguinte forma.. não sei se é o mais certo mas deu certo:

Comment: Talvez uma solução seja colocar 3 parametros, da uma olhada na nova consulta.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = $_GET["revenda"];
$var2 = $_GET["bemdesc"];
$var3 = $_GET["bemdesc"];

$query = ("SELECT bem, des_bem, revenda FROM AFX_BEM WHERE revenda LIKE :rev AND ( des_bem LIKE :bd OR bem LIKE :bd2 ) "); 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':rev', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':bd', '%' . $var2 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':bd2',   $var3  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```